# How to upgrade from Identity Server 4 v3.1.4 to v4.0.0 to not lose data?

Tags: identityserver4

I need to upgrade from IdS 4 from 3.1.4 to 4.0.0, a lots of tables change between 3.1.4 and 4.0.0 but I can't find any migration tool or process. I can upgrade my nuget packate to 4.0.0 and generate migration but it will drop and recreate the tables, what about data inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an article from the horse's mouth here:

https://www.identityserver.com/articles/migrating-your-identityserver4-v3-database-to-identityserver4-v4